# Aurora Lambda trigger - What does the received event look like?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-aurora

I am looking to implement a [Lambda trigger on AWS Aurora](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraPostgreSQL-Lambda.html), but I cannot find any information on what the event looks like when the Lambda is invoked. Do we receive a payload containing the table, database and other relevant context?

Answer (score 0):

The payload is provided by the caller, there is no strict format, so pretty much you could adapt for your cases.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/PostgreSQL-Lambda.html#PostgreSQL-Lambda-RequestResponse